# A loop to get "Time to first of results" instead of ifelse statement

Tags: r

I want to calculate "Time to first of results <200".
So I made a dataset and code to estimates as follow.
Is it possible to make this code(code (1) and code (2)) in to a "loop" using "for loop"?
Thank you in advance.

## (1) df1 is the data set of patients who has at least of one result of <200

```
df1<-df[(df$results<200)|(df$result2<200)|(df$result3<200)|(df$result4<200)|(df$result5<200),]
```

## (2) Time to first of results <200

```
df_2<-df_1%>%
  mutate(first_period=
           ifelse(df_1$result1<200,date1,
                  ifelse(df_1$result2<200,date2,
                         ifelse(df_1$result3<200,date3,
                                ifelse(df_1$result4<200,date4,
                                       ifelse(df_1$result5<200,date5,date6))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
default <- "default"
number_of_patients <- 6

col_names <- paste("result", 1:number_of_patients)
# c("result1", "result2", ..., "result6")

dates # should contain date1, date2, ..., date6

patient_date_first_under_200 <- function(df_1, col_names, dates, number_of_patients, default="default-value") {
  for (i in 1:number_of_patients) {
    if (df_1[, col_names[i]] < 200) {
      return(dates[i])
    }
  }
  default
}

# in case that result1, ... result6 are the only columns of df_1:



patient_date_first_under_200 <- function(df, dates, default="default-value") {
  col_names <- colnames(df)
  for (i in 1:ncol(df)) {
    if (df[, col_names[i]] < 200) {
      return(dates[i])
    }
  }
  default
}
```

But there is something strange with your data structuring. Why you have for each patient's result one extra column on your data frame?
Which row is the value? How many rows has your data frame?
Is `date` one of the rows in this table?

Usually you use vectorization in R, because it is the fastest.

If the data would be ordered in a way, that the results are in one column of `df` - let's say with the name `result`, and all corresponding dates are in a column `date`, you could do:

```
df$date[df$result < 200][1]
```

And it would be blazingly fast. (Except in the case the rows - number of patients - is really huge ...)

As a function this would be:

```
get_date <- function(df, return_col="date", query_col="result", limit = 200, default = "no result") {
  res <- df[, return_col][df[, query_col] < limit]
  ifelse(length(res) == 0, default, res[1]) # on no-match return default
}
```

This would return `default` value if no match found. Otherwise the first match's result column's value.

Comment: Hello gwang-jin, thanks for your help! Can I ask why you put default <- "default" and function(df, dates, default="default-value") in the function?  Regard your question,  at first my data was in the long form with date and result in one column for each. However I couldn't make the function for this because if the id never reaches to result <200, I couldn't get the last date.

Comment: Good point to cover he case that no element matches the condition `< 200`. See my last part of the answer. The `df$date[df$result < 200]` if no match is there, returns `integer(0)` which one can test for wtih `length(res) == 0`. In that case what is given as `default` value should be returned, otherwise the first match.

Comment: I generalized the function so that one can determine the return column and the query column and also can adjust the limit of 200 and also the default value.

Comment: For uniformity of return type, the best actually would be to choose a date long ago - so that e.g. a difference to a certain other date would become negative or bigger than soandso years or months or days - so that it is easily testable for it for case-distinctions.